# Uploading youtube videos to the site

Tags: files

I would like to be able to upload youtube videos to the new site I am currently building. I would like to have a page which will list ALL the youtube videos uploaded, and then on the homepage, I would like to have a single video selected from the list of already uploaded youtube videos (changeable).

I would like it to be as simple as possible. I was thinking of a YouTube Field module. Is this simple enough?

I was thinking of possibly using Views to list all the Youtube Videos... but how would I embed the one on the homepage?

Any feedback and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I recently tried a module that allows you to upload your videos via your website to Youtube. Check it out:

http://drupal.org/project/video_upload

On the other hand, if you simply want to integrate existing Youtube videos to your website (as fields), simply use the Media modules:

First of all, you need Embedded Media Field module: 
http://drupal.org/project/emfield

Then install Media: Youtube to integrate your videos: 
_http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube

You can list, sort, filter all your nodes (that contain your video field) very easily with views.

I hope this help, feel free to ask some more details.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/youtube did the trick. Thank you.